# Trying to return partialview from try catch block

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

So i've created a custom authorise attribute that checks if a user is in a given group of the ad and does the check and if so will authorise and let them through to the controller or whatever, this all works fine.

Problem i've got now is trying to catch if a user isn't authenticated and returning them to an error page, but can't return PartialView from the catch statement, and unsure how to achieve a similar outcome, code is below.

```
public string Group { get; set; }

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Group))
  {
      return true;
  }

  try
  {
    return LDAPHelper.isInGroup(username, Group);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't `LDAPHelper.isInGroup(username, Group);` return false if the user is not in the group?

Comment: Sorry, i rushed this question and should have added more details, it does indeed pass me back a false value if they're not authenticated but upon this false value, i'm looking to return an error page.

Comment: Then why do you need a `try..catch` block? Why not have `if(!LDAPHelper.isInGroup(username, Group))` and then return your page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two articles about proper Exception handling and throwing, that I consider required reading everytime something like catch Exception pops up in Problem description code:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Throwing an exception on having the wrong rights might be a Vexing Excetpion case. In any case, Catching Exception is a really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the articles, and I will look through them, can you elaborate why case catching exception is bad?

Comment: You end up catching Fatal Exceptions (OOM, Index out of Bounds), wich will cause massive and unpredictable followup issues that will be impossible to diagnose. Catch only what you expect the Function throws and never something Fatal.
The bigger question is if throwing a Exception on "not enough Rights" is a case of vexing Exception or not. These kind of exception are at the border. And it depends how you generally do the programm flow if they are a wise idea. In paritcualr it matters how likely this case happens - do not throw exception on highly likely cases.